# How to add a class to the <a> tag within <li> yii bootstrap navbar

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have looked around extensively to find a solution to this, but I have had no luck what so ever. I'm sure it must be simple, but I'm very new to this and can't quite figure it out.

Any pointers would be amazing!

I currently have this:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'HOME', 'url'=>array('/site/index'), 'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'home_btn')),
                array('label'=>'DEMO', 'url'=>array('/site/demo'), 'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'demo_btn')),              
//              array('label'=>'My Account', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'myaccount')),
//              array('label'=>'Signup', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'signup')),             
//              array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
//              array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("JOIN"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
//              array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Profile"), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'myaccount'), 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("My Account"), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout").' ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),

                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->loginUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("MEMBERS AREA"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),

            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I can get the class on the < li> but I need to get it on the various < a> tags created by yii. e.g

```
<a href=#" class="demo_btn">Blah</a>
```

If any more info would help, or anything else, more than happy to pass it on.

Many thanks,

Ali

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have `<li class="style"> <a href="#">texr</a></li>`

then you may refer `<a>` in css like this way

```
.style a{/*...css..*/} and .style a:hover{/*...css..*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#items-detail

linkOptions: array, optional, additional HTML attributes to be rendered for the link or span tag of the menu item.
itemOptions: array, optional, additional HTML attributes to be rendered for the container tag of the menu item.